# Проверка логина

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, post, фильтрация

Скажите пожалуйста, такая проверка логина хорошая или плохая. Или дайте пожалуйста лучший пример. И вообще, нужна ли такая проверка если я использую ActiveRecord?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli();

        $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;

        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);

        if (!preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*?([-_][a-z0-9]+){0,2}$/i', $username)) {
            $username = null;
        }
```

Comment: Чо за фрамеворк ,YII  ?

Comment: Вы лучше скажите какие имена вы такой проверкой хотите пропускать, а какие нет.

Comment: А зачем вам `username` проверять по регуляркам ? пусть вводить чо хотит.

Comment: @phpХ я увидел ошибку в вашей регулярке, если оставить так то username может содержать всего одну букву, и это пройдет через `regex`, а это вам нужно?

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan да это не для регистрации. :) а для аутентификации.

Comment: Значит регуляркой проверять глупо?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, о, покажите пожалуйста мою ошибку? Это просто я взял готовый пример.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan нет это не Yii. Просто использую данную библиотеку в самописном "доморощенном" фреймворке, если конечно это можно назвать фреймворком

Comment: @phpХ Вот здесь напишите вашу регулярку и можете сделать тест, если даешь ему всего одну букву он проходит регулярку, значит человек может внести всего одну букву  в `username` и пройти регистрацию.
Вот сайт: http://regexr.com/

Comment: Зачем вам вообще перед аунтификацией проверять логин, если нет в базе значит не правильный.

Comment: @Naumov понял. Т.е. здесь ведь просто идет проверка на соответствие, поэтому с проверкой незачем заморачиваться? Хорошо, а для регистрации такой ход подойдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/book.filter.php вот, почитайте. Эфективнее и красивее будет использовать валидацию и санитизацию, хорошо описаные в ссылке выше.
А чтобы не бояться что вашу БД вскроют стоит обрать внимание на расширение PDO и подготовленые запросы http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Comment: Спасибо! Раздел фильтров я как-то упустил из виду.